# reset style after click in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need help to reset style after click panel in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flip").click(function(){
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
$("#wrapper").css("height","900px");
$("#wrapper").css("background-size","… 700px");
});
```

How I reset div (wrapper) to origin style:

```
$("#wrapper").css("height","600px");
$("#wrapper").css("background-size","4… 500px");
```

Can help me please!!

Comment: Possible duplicat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944874/how-to-reset-elements-to-their-original-state-after-a-chain-of-manipulations

Comment: when to reset???? on which event?

Comment: on unclick event (I can't write this)

Answer (score 1):

Create css like this :

```
.original{
     height:"600px";
     background-size:"500px";
}
.temp{
     height:"900px";
     background-size:"700px";
}
```

Add, remove or toggle class to change style :

`$("#wrapper").toggleClass('original temp')`

Answer (score 0):

```
Place your default style for the div immediately after ready function before click event.

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#wrapper").css("height","600px");
$("#wrapper").css("background-size","4… 500px");

$("#flip").click(function(){
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
$("#wrapper").css("height","900px");
$("#wrapper").css("background-size","… 700px");
});
```